# how to properly apply Core Image filter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, core-image

Im having a trouble with Core image.  what I'm doing is getting an image from a UIImageView and then use some code i found in tutorials (I'm new to core Image) but then I want to put the sepia image back into the same same UIImageView when ever I try to put the new image into the view it just disappears I have tested to see if the image view contains an image and it does but it is not visible. any suggestions on what to do?

EDIT:
okay I got the sepia filter to work so then I tried posterize and i had the same problem the image just disappears.  Here is the code:

```
CIImage *beginImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[image_view.image CGImage]];
context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorPosterize" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, beginImage,@"inputLevels",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8], nil];
CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];
CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
[image_view setImage:newImg];
CGImageRelease(cgimg);
```

Comment: Post the code you have thus far!!!

Comment: There are CoreImage filters missing from the iOS SDK. I believe posterize is one of them. Google for iOS supported CoreImage filters for the list of supported ones.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try something like this (let say you have an UIImageView *myImageView)

```
CIImage *beginImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[myImageView.image CGImage]];
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone" keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, @"inputIntensity", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8], nil];
CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];

CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];

[myImageView setImage:newImg];

CGImageRelease(cgimg);
```

Comment: The source for this answer: http://www.raywenderlich.com/22167/beginning-core-image-in-ios-6

Comment: Or this: http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2011/12/31/core-image-framework-in-ios-5-0/ or this: http://books.google.com/books?id=ANOhiaaOwjAC&pg=PA633&lpg=PA633&dq=cisepiatone&source=bl&ots=aRg2fklJUm&sig=8eb3ThWDPwqmkz0ZN-8WHZQLb6w&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-_XPU8mkDIeCzAP40oKYCw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=cisepiatone&f=false or this http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/apply-image-filters-using-coreimage-framework-in-ios/2/ or ...

Answer (score 0):

Same code in Swift 3.0 on Xcode 8.2 (My imageView in project is "@IBOutlet var photoImageView : UIImageView!") 
Checked successfully on an iPhone 7Plus device iOS 10

```
    guard let myImageView = self.photoImageView.image else
    {
        return
    }
    guard let cg = myImageView.cgImage else
    {
        return
    }
    let beginImage = CIImage(cgImage: cg)
    let context : CIContext = CIContext(options: nil)
    let inputParams : [String : Any]? = [kCIInputImageKey : beginImage,
                                        "inputIntensity" : NSNumber(value : 0.8)]
    let filter : CIFilter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone", withInputParameters: inputParams)!
    let outputImage : CIImage? = filter.outputImage!

    if let outputImage = outputImage
    {
        let cgImage : CGImage? = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent)!

        if let cg = cgImage
        {
            let newImage : UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cg)
            photoImageView.image = newImage
        }
    }
```